# RFID reader port settings

Tags: serial-port, rfid, payload, parity, baud-rate

I'm using an [RFID reader](https://www.smart-technologies.eu/en/product-overview/rfid-mounting-reader/rfid-mounting-reader-mcr) connected to my computer over RS232 to usb port. It is using COM3 port with default settings (9600, 1 stopbit, no parity etc). After scanning a test card it gives me a nonesensical response, something like ··½w»··{íë

I think I tried almost all combinatios of baud rate, parity etc and I'm not getting a "normal" UID reponse. What could be a problem here? I don't know much about RFID and I can only assume that the test cards are ok. How can I find the correct settings? I contacted the supplier but I'm still waiting for a response.

Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get anything... Only 1 paper with connection pins descriptions for power supply, rx and tx. I'm using Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (rs232 to usb). I searched all over the internet for this info and cant find it.

Comment: Then you need to use an oscilloscope to verify the serial port parameters.  Start by measuring the TxD voltage range.  Then find the shortest intervals between transitions; the inverse of that time is the approximate baudrate.   "*it gives me a nonesensical response...*" -- Maybe you need to examine the response in binary/hex representation instead of ASCII?  IOW the response from the reader is not likely to be text. The response format could also depend on which of the 5 types of card reader you have. At this point you don't have a programming question.  Vote to close.